# How to add custom header or title and footer information of company in csv export option of datatable?

Tags: jquery, csv, datatables

I am using dataTables and trying to add new feature where I can add customized title information or can say customize header and footer information.

So what I am trying to do is to add customize company information into CSV file when someone press CSV button on datatables options of export table information.

like here:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

and what I am keen to use is following option "**customize**" define by datatables here: https://datatables.net/reference/button/csv

So as in above link one of the option of CSV is called customize - **where I can achieve to add customize information in CSV file but I don't know how I can use this customize option**. So if someone give me jsfiddle example or some hint would be really helpful guys.:)

Apart from my question I did some research and found following which is useful but don't know in excel and csv what can be used:

```
dom: 'Bftripl',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
        //'csvHtml5',
        //'pdfHtml5',
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            customize: function (doc) {
                doc.content.splice(1, 0, {
                    margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                    alignment: 'center',
                    image: 'data:image/png;base64,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'
                });
            }
        },
```

From here:
[how to customize export to csv,excel,pdf in jquery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352181/how-to-customize-export-to-csv-excel-pdf-in-jquery-datatables)

I have asked this question here as well: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38275/how-to-use-csv-customize-option-in-dattable-export-csv-button?new=1

but still no idea for csv???

Comment: Have you ever seen a CSV with header and footer? Or a CSV with embedded images? Also, the `.xslx` is not a fancy excel-sheet-generator, it exports a CSV in a format that is more readable for excel.

Comment: Haha I have seen, but the point is if datatables provide a function for customize something then it suppose to be working right? And all point here is we can't argument with clients about this sorts of thing hey? and secondly above is just example with image actually, I want to put some header information where say "Company XYZ details of year 2016" and in footer information where say "This data is just for example purpose only or may not relate to actual data." - So the point is to put header and footer in excel and csv.

Comment: Please point me to an example of a CSV having header and footer :) Or embedded images ...

Comment: Hi, well you should find it by yourself and that's fine leave it as I am more keen to looking forward to an answer rather than discussing it that whether csv have any additional information on above the table data or below the table data.thx

Answer (score 5):

I hope some will come up with something but nothing come up. However, as I found lot of people looked at though.

Anyways, I have found answer for csv but still didn't find anything for excel. So will make another question for it but for CSV answer is as follows:

```
{
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
              customize: function (csv) {
                 return "My header here....\n\n"+  csv +"\n\nMy Footer here.....";
              }
        }
```

Thanks to allan - datatable expert and get back to me without arguing that whether I have seen any csv with header and footer. So thanks to allan and you can see original answer here:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38275

Thanks and have a look:)